# Adding values into a dictionary from a module

Tags: python, dictionary, module, python-module

Is there a way to add values into a dictionary thats defined in a different script?

```
file_1.py 
dictionary = {1:1, 2:2}

file2.py
from file_1 import dictionary as d

for i in range(10):
  if i not in d:
    d[i] = i 

desired result
file_1.py 
dictionary = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9}
```

I try this but the dictionary in file_1 doesn't change. Is there a way to do this without file reading and just appending values into the dictionary?

Comment: This is limited to your file2, when file3 imports file1 dictionary will be unaltered. Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: To create a cache that stores the values for later use.